# ElasticSearch and Apm search phase execution exception: [script_exception] Reason: link error

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, elastic-stack, open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I installed ElasticSrarch and Kibana after that added integrated fleet and Apm on windows server 2019 and 2022 (both active now and all stack version is 8.1.2). for client I use AspNetCore sample form [OpenTelemetry Github repository](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/examples). I haven't any problem When I send Apm to windows server 2022 but when I send to 2019 and try access apm services from observability I get below error.
[image]

And this error logged:

```
[2022-04-18T14:34:22.619+04:30][ERROR][plugins.apm] Error: search_phase_execution_exception: [script_exception] Reason: link error
    at D:\ElasticStack\kibana\x-pack\plugins\observability\common\utils\unwrap_es_response.js:60:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at getServiceInstancesSystemMetricStatistics (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\x-pack\plugins\apm\server\routes\services\get_service_instances\get_service_instances_system_metric_statistics.js:126:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at D:\ElasticStack\kibana\x-pack\plugins\apm\server\routes\services\get_service_instances\main_statistics.js:28:51
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at handler (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\x-pack\plugins\apm\server\routes\services\route.js:622:45)
    at D:\ElasticStack\kibana\x-pack\plugins\apm\server\routes\apm_routes\register_apm_server_routes.js:143:13
    at Router.handle (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\src\core\server\http\router\router.js:163:30)
    at handler (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\src\core\server\http\router\router.js:124:50)
    at exports.Manager.execute (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:60:28)
    at Object.internals.handler (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at exports.execute (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at Request._lifecycle (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:371:32)
    at Request._execute (D:\ElasticStack\kibana\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:281:9)
Response: {
  error: {
    root_cause: [
      {
        type: 'script_exception',
        reason: 'link error',
        script_stack: [ "doc['system.memory.actual.free']", '     ^---- HERE' ],
        script: "1 - doc['system.memory.actual.free'] / doc['system.memory.total']",
        lang: 'expression'
      }
    ],
    type: 'search_phase_execution_exception',
    reason: 'all shards failed',
    phase: 'query',
    grouped: true,
    failed_shards: [
      {
        shard: 0,
        index: '.ds-metrics-apm.internal-default-2022.04.17-000001',
        node: 'KsqpLySITbOWAlCPlvsdSg',
        reason: {
          type: 'script_exception',
          reason: 'link error',
          script_stack: [ "doc['system.memory.actual.free']", '     ^---- HERE' ],
          script: "1 - doc['system.memory.actual.free'] / doc['system.memory.total']",
          lang: 'expression',
          caused_by: {
            type: 'parse_exception',
            reason: 'Field [system.memory.actual.free] does not exist in mappings'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  status: 400
}
```

I compare both servers and agents configs but I can't find any differences. Why this message and error appears and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem two weeks ago, and After some busy days, I will send it here. Also, I think It's a bug.
In a general and fast answer, you should add APM metrics that contain CPU and memory benchmarks. In the below lines, I describe my case in detail.
Windows Server 2022 VPS is a development test environment, and I started my project with the Elastic APM library. This library collects CPU and memory metrics and sends them as APM Metrics by default configurations. After that, I changed my library and used OpentTelemetry. The new one does not send CPU and memory benchmarks, and I ignore it on tests because it's not noticeable for my usage. When I moved from the development to the staging environment with a clean installation of Elastic, an error appeared. After some debugging, I find that the problem solves if I add CPU and Memory metrics. I added metrics by sending them with my first Elastic APM Library, but others can use Kibana and add some fake metrics. For the second approach, you can see the Ovidiu [comment](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/apm-system-memory-actual-free-and-system-memory-total-not-exists-in-mapping/303359/4?u=shahin_ke).